# Is roboearth going through an intense week of migrating to fuerte?

Tags: roboearth

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I have noticed that in past 7/8 days, roboearth source has changed very vigorously. I have been able to install roboearth on ubuntu 12.04 with fuerte. However, when running re_object_recorder gui, when I try to save the model, i get the following error:
OpenCV is NOT compiled with SURF support.

This problem, I am assuming comes from the fact that SURF and SIFT are now patented and are available with OpenCV as 3rd-party nonfree libraries.

Could this be the reason why I was not able to save models?
Has this problem been/being resolved at the moment?

I will appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37152/is-roboearth-going-through-an-intense-week-of-migrating-to-fuerte?/) by [bakhol](https://answers.ros.org/users/2684/bakhol/) on ROS Answers with karma: 196 on 2012-06-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sorry, this was my mistake, I guess I was a bit careless with committing. As I am currently not at my office, I will fix this next week when I am back.

---

Originally posted by [ddimarco](https://answers.ros.org/users/1073/ddimarco/) with karma: 916 on 2012-06-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2